# Word meaning crying, but not crying?

Tags: single-word-requests, phrase-requests

You know when you see something touching and moving and you feel like tears are about to come out of your eyes, yet you're able to barely control it; how do you describe this feeling or state?
 i.e. *I was all [...] at the sight of his master curled up asleep in fetal position on the floor at the vet's beside his dog.*

Take a look at this and you'll know what I'm talking about:

[image]

Comment: The word *kitsch* comes to mind.

Comment: I was ***close to tears***?

Answer (score 28, accepted):

I was all [choked up](http://idioms.thefreedictionary.com/choke+up).

> Fig. to cause someone to feel like starting to cry.

I got all [misty-eyed](http://www.thefreedictionary.com/misty-eyed).

> 1. Having the eyes blurred, as with tears.

Answer (score 12):

..............[I felt the tears welling up.](http://www.thefreedictionary.com/well+up)

Answer (score 10):

> I was all teary at the sight of his master curled up asleep...

**teary**; *of a person, having eyes filled with tears; inclined to cry; Of eyes, filled with tears*

Answer (score 8):

Another option would be **verklemmt**

It is a Yiddish word describing a strong emotional response.

From [Wikipedia:](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Verklempt#V)

> verklemmt: choked up; speechless; unable to express one's feelings/emotions (cf. German verklemmt = "uptight"); stuck

Comment: I think this is a great word for the situation described. You'll sometimes see this spelled *verklempt*.

Comment: Unfortunately, thanks to Mike Myers and Saturday Night Live, this word now has mostly humorous connotations.  (At least to American readers.)  Its original definition has been somewhat subsumed by this, and it might break the tone if you're writing something serious and not comedic.

Answer (score 6):

Try one of these:

I felt a sting at the back of my eyes

I felt a lump in my throat

Comment: Is *feeling a sting at the back of eyes* common usage? I like the non-literal sense to these phrases.

Comment: One would not use it in everyday usage, but neither is the sentiment something you convey everyday. However in fiction, specially when building up a moment or atmosphere, it is used.

Answer (score 4):

## *On Tears of Joy and Gladness*

For what purpose and in what linguistic context?

- Written or oral, and if so, what is the context of each?
- Talking to someone at a pub?
- Declaiming poetry, and if so, is it open verse or otherwise?
- **High register** or casual?
- Is this a medical audience, perhaps even **ophthalmologists**?
- Is it for the stranger sitting next to you on the city bus?

I myself would use any the more run-of-mill alternatives already given, or perhaps something more lyrical if sufficiently stirred, ranging from the commonplace to the poetic:

- I was touched, stirred, or moved.
- I could only say *awwwwwww* and smile like a happy idiot.
- I got all choked up.
- I got all teary-eyed.
- My eyes misted over.
- I spilt tender tears.
- The touching scene so warmed the cold cockles of my heart that my eyes welled up with tears of joy unlooked for — and all the more welcome for it.

The thing is that we more often associate tears with negative emotions than we do with positive ones.  However, any emotion that’s powerful enough can so overwhelm us as to provoke a **lachrymal** response. However, English doesn’t distinguish in a single word the **tears of *gladness*** from **tears of *sadness***.

In either case, we just say that someone was crying or weeping, but that does not tell the full tale.  The tears of the plaint look the same as those that spring from sorrow’s opposite.  As [one of the Wise](http://www.elvish.org/gwaith/epitaph_1.htm) one remarked in a bittersweet parting:

> *I will not say: do not weep; for not all tears are an evil.*

If not all tears are evil nor all weeping that of sadness, how do we tell the one from the other.  We’ve no choice but to add other words to tell the difference between the two, for we have no special word in English that would immediately distinguish the **bitter tears of dyscatastrophe and sadness** from  the **sweet tears of eucatastrophe and gladness**.

Metaphorically then, tears can be either bitter or they can be sweet, or perhaps both at once.  In reality of course, both are equally salty, despite [the Chicago song “Make Me Smile” inviting one to “Cry **sweet** tears of joy”](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=NifeiFF2Ufo).

It is this inherent ambiguity of the different kinds of tears that resists a single word to tell the bitter from the sweet, let alone from the bittersweet, that makes this question a difficult to one to answer succinctly and unambiguously.  Tears can even suddenly transform from one form to the other, as the psalmist wrote in [*Psalms* 30:5](http://www.biblegateway.com/passage/?search=Psalm+30%3A5&version=KJV), when the night’s weeping turns to joy with the coming of the dawn.

### Sesquipedalianisms

I have already given several common ways of saying it, but if you want a more high-falutin’ term, both *lachrymous* and ***lachrymose*** exist, with the latter being by far the more common of the two.

The OED gives two subsenses for its sense two of that word:

> - **2a.** Given or ready to shed tears. Of the eyes: **Suffused with tears**.
> - **2b.** Of a tearful character; calculated to provoke tears; **mournful**.

Although sense 2a gives you want you want, sense 2b’s tenebrous overtones might risk miscommunication if the full context were not well established.

The OED has a bunch of entries starting with *lachrym-*, but most are confined to technical medical usage today:

> - † lachrymable [adj.]
> - † lachrymabund [adj.]
> - `‖` lachryma Christi [n.]
> - lachrymal [adj.]
> - › lachrymal canal, duct, gland, sac, lachrymal bone, sinus, lachrymal fistula ← lachrymal
> - lachrymary [adj.]
> - lachrymate [v.]
> - ˈlachrymating [vbl. n.] ← lachrymate
> - lachrymation [n.]
> - lachrymator [n.]
> - lachrymatory [adj.]
> - † lachryme [n.]
> - † lachryˈmental [adj.]
> - lachrymiform [adj.]
> - lachrymist [n.]
> - lachrymogenic [adj.]
> - ˌlachrymo-ˈnasal [adj.]
> - lachrymose [adj.]
> - ˈlachrymosely [adv.] ← lachrymose
> - lachryˈmosity ← lachrymose
> - lachrymous [adj.]

Whereas for the more expected *lacr-* prefix, it has next to nothing: one is *lacrimal* which it says is an alternate spelling of *lachrymal*, and the other is the unassimilated foreign phrase [*lacrimae rerum*](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lacrimae_rerum)<sup>†</sup>, the “tears of things” from Virgil’s *Aeneid*.

† <sub>[*For once, I strongly advise following the link and reading the brief Wikipedia article in full, for there is true poetic beauty there in some of the English translations*.]</sub>

---

### A Minor Spelling Mystery

I wonder where the funny spelling of the English *la**chry**mose* (etc.) came from.

For those familiar with the [Requiem Masses](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Requiem) of [Mozart](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Ym8b3bC_Fq4) or [Verdi](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=ohwWBT8rW2M), or even [Berlioz](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=fGiiOcd7oGc) if you’re into that sort of thing, you will recognize these famous words from the *Dies Irae* set to their own movements by those composers. The very first word is the one from which our modern one in English ultimately derives:

> ***Lacrimosa** dies illa
>
>   Qua resurget ex favilla
>
>   Judicandus homo reus.
>
>   Huic ergo parce, Deus:
>
>   Pie Jesu Domine,
>
>   Dona eis requiem. Amen.*

It all comes back to a *lacrima* meaning a tear in Latin, which gives us *lágrima* in modern Spanish, Portuguese, and Galician alike, and *llàgrima* in neighboring Catalan.  It’s still just *lacrima* in Italian just like the “original” Latin, and similarly still stressed on the the ante-penult as all four Iberian orthographies make clear via their explicit diacritics.

French has whittled it all the way down to *la larme* for tear, but *liquide lacr**y**mal* is still known: notice they have a *y* there now in French, which seems to be where we got ours from, but still no *h* as in the English version.

What I do not understand is where the extra *h* came from in English *lac**h**rymose*, or the *y* for that matter.  Latin didn’t have it; as shown above, Latin had *lacrimōs-us* for the adjective and *lacrima* for the 1st-declension feminine noun.

The *‑chry‑* sequence looks much more Greek to me than the *‑cri‑* Latin sequence, but we got it from Latin. But modern Greek, I think, just has *δακρυσμένος* (“dakrysménos”) there from *δάκρυ(α)* (“dákry(a)”), so I don’t know why the Latin-derived word should now have a pseudo-Greek spelling in English.

All I can guess is that the medievals somehow got the  *‑cri‑* part in Latin *lacrimosa* confused with ***χρῡσ**-ός*, (*“chrȳs-ós”*) Greek for gold and common in chemistry and taxonomy: ***chrys**oberyl* is a yellowish-green gem and the golden eagle is *Aquila **chrys**aëtos*.  Must ask Cerberus.

Then again, *lacrimosa* and *dakrysménos* and such are close enough to make me wonder about some previously unknown Grimm ***d–l*** swap back in PIE. Must ask John Lawler.

---

### *Addendum*

As mentioned in potentially ephemeral comments below, Janus has explained that ***d–l*** swaps were not wholly unknown in early Latin variants. Lest his comment be someday lost, I copy it here for posterity [**emphasis** mine]:

> Quite unrelated to the above, and only a comment on the very last bit of this answer: **the d/l switch is not all that uncommon in Latin.** Original initial d’s occasionally show up in Latin as l’s. Compare *lingua* with its Oscan (or is it Umbrian?) cognate *fangvam* and earlier Latin form *dingua*, as well as the Archaic Latin form *dacruma/dacrima.*

So it seems more certain that the Latin word and the Greek word were related after all.  But why the medievals thought to use *‑ch‑* as though it had had a chi not a kappa in the Greek, we will probably never know.  It smells like what [Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/English-language_spelling_reform) is referring to when it writes:

> From the 16<sup>th</sup> century onward, English writers who were scholars of Greek and Latin literature tried to link English words to their Graeco-Latin counterparts. They did this by adding silent letters to make the real or imagined links more obvious. Thus *det* became *debt* (to link it to Latin *debitum*), *dout* became *doubt* (to link it to Latin *dubitare*), *sissors* became *scissors* and *sithe* became *scythe* (as they were wrongly thought to come from Latin *scindere*), *iland* became *island* (as it was wrongly thought to come from Latin *insula*), *ake* became *ache* (as it was wrongly thought to come from Greek *ἄχος* (*“akhos”*), and so forth.

Considering that *lachrymose* entered English during the 17<sup>th</sup> century, is seems to be of the same sort of thing as *thyme*: late medieval Latin often simply had *timum* or *timus*, but then somebody noticed that Greek had *θύμον* (*θύμος* < *θύειν* to burn sacrifice) so they when back and put in letters we never said, first into the Latin *thymum* and then into English *thyme*.

The story of why we spell the River *Thames* with an *h*, a word which King Ælfred himself spelt merely ***Temes*** around 893, is even sillier, when 610 years after that the Rolls of Parliament first recorded it with an *h* in 1503:

> A Ryvere called the ***Thamyse***, otherwyse called the *Temmesse*.

Here there is no Greek theta in anything original, so they just got it wrong. However, unlike other notoriously respelled words like *author* < *autor* and *Anthony* < *Antoni(us)*, the River’s name was too commonly said to tolerate an erroneous theta pronunciation.

Comment: -1 Your answer is, as far as I can tell, off-topic. As thought provoking it is, I don't think the OP is really concerned with the spelling idiosyncrasies of the word *lachrymose*. And finally, the OP made it pretty clear what the context was.

Comment: @Mari-LouA: SUre it's on topic. Lachrymose' is a perfectly good synonym for teary-eyed. You may disagree that that is a good alternative for the OP, but it is certainly on topic.

Comment: @Mari-LouA: So let me get this straight. You're down-voting because tchrist did more than was required? He *always* does more than is required. Don't hold it against him. There are plenty of shorter answers that ought to be right in your wheelhouse. Read one of those instead. Now I have to up-vote just to cancel out your misguided censure.

Comment: @Mari-Lou: I have to join the chorus. I like you, but I find this down-vote, and especially your comment, unbelievable. Is there some personal vendetta going on or something? The answer gives no less than four straightforward options that answer the question exactly; contrary to what you are saying, the question does not provide the kind of context this answer has requested; and, lastly, it is the only answer that is actually interesting and learned. The academically inclined will not doubt be interested in the background story behind one of the answers to the OP's question. Please reconsider.

Comment: @Cerberus There is no personal vendetta. Why should there be? I have nothing against the word, lachrymose either, off-topic was perhaps the wrong word. But tchrist's "spelling mystery" has nothing to do with the OP's question. And the context is pretty clear in the OP's question, so I find his premise questionable.

Comment: Just to be clear, I was tempted to leave an anonymous downvote but I didn't. I know tchrist is a very respected and well-liked member of ELU; and the fact his friends have rallied round is credit to him. I publicly expressed and justified my downvote. I wish others would do likewise.

Comment: Quite unrelated to the above, and only a comment on the very last bit of this answer: the d/l switch is not all that uncommon in Latin. Original initial d's occasionally show up in Latin as l's. Compare _lingua_ with its Oscan (or is it Umbrian?) cognate _fangvam_ and earlier Latin form _dingua_, as well as the Archaic Latin form _dacruma/dacrima_.

Comment: @JanusBahsJacquet Thanks, I didn’t know about *dingua* or *dacruma/dacryma*, having studied no Latin earlier than the classical period let alone neighboring forms (Ask me about modern Romance variants though :). Finally I can see how it is indeed related to the Greek without having to drag up sound laws from Grimm or such. The medievals seems to have like the *-chry-* spelling for no good reason (even Greek would have had kappa there) here as in so many other places.

Comment: @JanusBahsJacquet: You're obviously right, but I wouldn't say it's "not all that uncommon", unless you know of many other such changes?

Comment: I'm fairly sure there are one or two more, but yeah—“not unheard of” would have been a better choice of words.

Comment: I'm not sure I understand the relevance of most of the second and the whole of the third (and naturally, the fourth) chapters of this post. The first is quite straight-forward, and the second starts to get digressive after the first paragraph. I'm not saying it isn't useful to someone, but I don't see its usefulness here. Does tracing the spelling back eventually yield additional candidates for the word?

Comment: A distinction between tears of joy/gladness and tears of sadness could be: eulachrymal and gaudilachrymal versus lachrymal or dyslachrymal or, perhaps, tristilachrymal from _tristi_ sad.

Comment: Welp surfing past this 4+ years later, I appreciated the answer.  I was looking for a word to describe how I felt this morning when my 7 year old son squeezed me when I asked if he wanted me to come along as a chaperone on his field trip.  I wanted to cry but tears of joy not sadness.  I settled on `heartwarming` at the time in a text to my wife, but that doesn't seem quite right - so I started searching and came across this.  Thank you @tchrist for explaining why I couldn't find the word because "English doesn’t distinguish in a single word the tears of gladness from tears of sadness."

Answer (score 2):

**dewy-eyed** covers the situation you describe pretty accurately.

For example, from [Cambridge Dictionaries](http://dictionary.cambridge.org/us/dictionary/british/dewy-eyed)

> having eyes that are wet with tears because you feel emotional:
>   *dewy-eyed nostalgia*

Comment: Although _dewy-eyed_ is an interesting suggestion, I'm not sure that it fits the context that the questioner has in mind. Here is the only definition of the term in _Merriam-Webster's Eleventh Collegiate Dictionary_ (2003): "**dewy-eyed** _adj_ (1938) : naively innocent and trusting {a _dewy-eyed_ optimist}." If you have access to a more relevant dictionary definition of _dewy-eyed_, you can strengthen your answer considerably by appending it to the original (and quite brief) answer.

Comment: @SvenYargs I think the naivety came after the near-tears description, with the idea of someone who was easily moved (emotionally). Updates as suggested

Answer (score 0):

**Teary-eyed**, *of a person, having tears in the eyes as when being overwhelmed by emotion*.

Crying or likely to cry. [Cambridge dictionary](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/teary-eyed)

Answer (score 0):

To describe the *moment* when you feel you're about to cry but can't, or you don't want to, here are  a few more suggestions:

1. [**on the verge of**](http://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/on-the-verge-of) **tears**
2. [**hover on the brink/verge/edge of**](http://www.macmillandictionary.com/dictionary/british/hover-on-the-brink-edge-verge-of-something) **tears**
   <sub>Annabel was hovering on the brink of tears.</sub>
3. [**close to**](http://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/close?q=close%20to) **tears**
   <sub>*Although close to ​tears, she ​tried to make her ​voice ​sound ​casual*.</sub>
4. **[brim](http://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/brim)**
   <sub>to ​become ​full of something, ​especially a ​liquid:

   *Her ​eyes brimmed with ​tears when she ​heard that he was ​alive*</sub>

Examples:

> I was *on the verge of tears* seeing the dog's owner curled up asleep beside him.
>
> My eyes *brimmed* with tears at the sight of his master curled up asleep in fetal position …

---

Sources: Cambridge Dictionaries, and Macmillan Dictionary

Answer (score 0):

Consider, *I was **on the ragged edge** of tears*

> ragged edge: (*Chiefly AmEng*) the extreme edge, like that of a precipice; verge: *the ragged edge of poverty*; ***Idiom***
>   on the ragged edge: precariously close to loss of self-control, mental stability, etc. [Webster's New World College Dictionary](http://www.yourdictionary.com/ragged-edge#tiqLQGgeJCeYRRgU.99)

Answer (score 0):

[*Misty-eyed*](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/misty%E2%80%93eyed), [*near to tears*](https://english.stackexchange.com/a/241072/50044), [*red eyed*](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/red%E2%80%93eyed) and *upset but not crying* are good phrases or words but there still is not a perfect answer yet.