# Meaning of "near tears" idiom

Tags: idioms

What is the meaning of "near tears" idiom?

Example:

> When I was 18, while hiking with a friend in Colorado, I tried to
>   impress him by climbing up a rock. A minute later, realizing I was
>   stuck, I called down to him, near tears.

Urban Dictionary describes idiom as "*a feeling of rapture*". But as I understand from example it has opposite meaning.

Comment: If someone is *near tears*, they are about to cry, from happiness, sadness, fear, or otherwise.

Comment: Is the quote you give from where Urban Dictionary says it is a 'feeling of rapture'? Aren't there other definitions given at UD?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> [Oxford Dictionary of English](https://books.google.ca/books?id=anecAQAAQBAJ&pg=PA1185&dq=%22near%20tears%22%20dictionary&hl=en&sa=X&ei=21w4VZDiA-a1sQSb74GwCA&redir_esc=y#v=onepage&q=%22near%20tears%22%20dictionary&f=false) - Page 1185 Angus Stevenson - 2010
>
> **near** preposition
>
> 3 **close to (a state); verging on**: *she gave a tiny smile, brave but
>   near tears* | *she was near to death*. 2a small amount below (another
>   amount): *temperatures near 2 million degrees*.