# How to describe the facial movements of a person before they cry?

Tags: single-word-requests, phrase-requests

Before a person cries, their facial muscles may have quick movements, like the muscles are vibrating. How would you describe that? Here is what I would say:

> "Her face twisted a second"

However, I don't think that represents what I am trying to say. Any suggestions to describe these facial movements?

Comment: ***quivering*** certainly describes the action but it is not specific to “pre-crying”

Comment: So, should I say "Her face quivered for a second."?

Comment: "pucker" ------

Comment: https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/134934/word-meaning-crying-but-not-crying

Comment: Winced.  Balled up his face.

Answer (score 1):

quiver, tremble, twitch all apply: quiver is perhaps more commonly-used in reference to strong emotion, particularly crying.

I checked my standard reference for such things - the Oxford English Dictionary.

For further reproducability, I add links to a Google NGram run:

[Face quivered, twitched, trembled- Google NGram](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=face%20quivered%2C%20face%20trembled%2C%20face%20twitched&year_start=1800&year_end=2012&corpus=15&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2Cface%20quivered%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cface%20trembled%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cface%20twitched%3B%2Cc0)

Comment: Please add sources to support your answer.

Answer (score 1):

Shiver - Tremor - quiver could express it I believe. However, if you intend to imply their shaking or quivering while crying, you could use **sob** since it suggests a more emotional form of crying.

[shiver](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/shiver)

[Tremor](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/tremor?q=Tremor)

[Sob](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/sob)